# Regarding freeing nodes while deleting them from Linked List

Tags: c, linked-list, free

Following is a function to delete duplicate elements in a Linked List

```
void deleteDup(Node *head)
{
    Node *ptr1, *ptr2, *prev;

    for (ptr1 = head; ptr1 != NULL; ptr1 = ptr1->next){

        prev = ptr1;

        for (ptr2 = ptr1->next; ptr2 != NULL; prev = ptr2, ptr2 = ptr2->next){
            if (ptr1->value == ptr2->value){
                prev->next = ptr2->next;
                free(ptr2);    // Question 1
            }
        }
    }    
}
```

**Question 1:** Above code works fine for `(1->1->2->3->1)`. But after completing it, I myself got confused.

Confusion: When it frees the ptr2 how does it moves forward in the loop? Shouldn't there be a seg fault at  `prev = ptr2, ptr2 = ptr2->next` after freeing ptr2?

**Question 2:** Can this code be optimized? (i.e. saving resources or improve performance)

Comment: @Jonathon general question: how do we format code fast while asking a question. I always get stuck with > or 4 space method

Comment: Select the code and click the **`{ }`** button. I manually fixed some indentation also.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Question 1:
There is indeed a problem. You have to expect undefined behaviour in general
(can, but does not have to be a segfault.
Can run without error too, but only "can", not will.

```
for (ptr2 = ptr1->next; ptr2 != NULL;){
    if (ptr1->value == ptr2->value){
        prev->next = ptr2->next;
        free(ptr2);    // Question 1
    }
    else prev = ptr2;
    ptr2 = prev->next;
}
```

Something like that should do (maybe. i´m tired.)

Question 2: Best memory optimization:
Get rid of the list with it´s pointers and use an array :p
Time opt.: Too. Other data structures are better suited for omething like that.
If you´re are willing to more memory during the process,
iterate the list and insert each element in a distinct data thing like some kind of tree
There you can easily check if a element has occured before
(and remove it from the list during this only one iterataion)

Comment: I appreciate your answer(1 vote is mine :)), but still why above works, what could be exact reason, this means free is useless or what?

Comment: No, free is not useless. What free does: Telling the OS that this memory is free and can be assigned to another new call or another program. What free does not: Overwriting the memory content with something else. In your case, you´re just lucky enough that the content doesn´t change between free and the last access to it. (or "un"lucky enough, because such problems might go unnoticed until something really bad happens. (I know a certain someone who wiped his HDD with his backup program. (Luckily, it really did a backup too, only erased the already-copied stuff.))

Comment: hmm..seems right, I wrote a quick code, pointer to int then stored 10 in it. Printed the value. Freed the pointer, printed the same value it  outputs 0. Any time and any number of time you do, it is always 0 after freeing. Is that the same as you said?

Comment: To be more precise: When you´re accessing memory which does not belong to your program (anymore), like free´d memory, it´s not predictable what will happen. Just plain undefined behaviour.

Comment: Okay, I trust you, moreover noone else replied

Answer (score 0):

Draw a diagram of the (part of the) structure like it looks at the beginning. Perhaps will need several to cover cases like the interesting node is the first/last/only one. Now do carefully each of the operations in the code on your diagram, checking after each step nothing went awry.

The same strategy works while figuring out how to do operations: diagram before/after, and see how to go from start to end.

Comment: That is what I expressed here, 1->1->2 once ptr2 is at middle 1, it should connect (first 1 and last 2) and then free ptr2, now how will for loop update itself without failing? (i.e. how will this ptr2 = ptr2->next execute?

Comment: @codeymodey, need much more detailed, step by step diagrams for *all* involved variables.